# Обновление autoincrement в таблице SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
public void avtoincrement(string table)
{
   SqlConnection sqlconnect = Conectiong();
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"ALTER TABLE " + table+ " AUTO_INCREMENT=0", sqlconnect);
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

данный метод дает ошибку некоректности запроса
как обновить автоинкремент?

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки в вашем вопросе.

Answer (score 2):

[DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, RESEED )
```

или

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ( table_name, RESEED, 0 )
```

Там разное поведение для пустых и непустых таблиц, так что подбирайте по ситуации